# How to specify the parameter layers in a WMS request?

Tags: google-maps, wms, google-maps-engine

I want to access my published and also public Google Maps Engine map via WMS.

I already have copied the link out of the map details. But I don't know how the parameter layers has to look like? What is its value?

As value I tried the name of the layer but it doesn't seem to work.
The response I get is "No data for requested layers" 
There is no white space in the name of my layer.

Answer (score 2):

Run GetCapabilities on the OGC link of your published map and it will tell you the layer names. For reference:

```
<Layer queryable="0">
    <Name>15658084116283052074-10602818151822182906-4</Name>
    <Title>x</Title>
    <Abstract/>
    <CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:3785</CRS>
    <CRS>EPSG:900913</CRS>
    <Layer queryable="0">
        <Name>15658084116283052074-00933023778830223306-4</Name>
        <Title>x</Title>
        <Abstract>Raster layer</Abstract>
        <CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
        <EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
          <westBoundLongitude>-100.00045742818516</westBoundLongitude>
          <eastBoundLongitude>-92.99988641904172</eastBoundLongitude>
          <southBoundLatitude>39.99928465598993</southBoundLatitude>
          <northBoundLatitude>47.00075398041749</northBoundLatitude>
        </EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
    </Layer>
</Layer>
```

My url looks like this:

```
https://mapsengine.google.com/15658084116283052074-10602818151822182906-4/wms/
?SERVICE=WMS
&REQUEST=GetMap
&VERSION=1.3.0
&LAYERS=15658084116283052074-10602818151822182906-4%2C15658084116283052074-00933023778830223306-4
&STYLES=
&FORMAT=image%2Fpng
&TRANSPARENT=true
&HEIGHT=256
&WIDTH=256
&CRS=EPSG%3A3857
&BBOX=-10644926.307106785,5361598.912035405,-10605790.548624776,5400734.670517417
```

Comment: how can i get the wms url for a layer created in vector form

Comment: add ?request=GetCapabilities to your wms link and paste what it says:   https://mapsengine.google.com/youridhere/wms/?REQUEST=GetCapabilities

Answer (score 0):

You can also find your layer IDs when using the web interface:

1. Open https://mapsengine.google.com/admin/
2. Click on "Layers"
3. Click the layer you want to use
4. In the URL, there will be an 'aid' parameter (e.g. &aid=15658084116283052074-10602818151822182906) - this number (pair of numbers) is the Asset ID of the layer, i.e. the layer ID.